# Handling startup/initialization Exceptions in VB .Net Console app (pre-Main(...))

Tags: .net, exception, console, initialization

Is it possible to catch startup/initialization exceptions (i.e., before Main(...) runs) in a VB .Net Console app?

There are lots of solutions that add Handlers for Thread and Unhandled exceptions in Main, but by the time Main is running, it's too late to catch startup/initialization exceptions.

For instance, is it possible to catch this exception:

```
Module Module1
    Private Class BrokenClass                   'Constructor is broken/misconfigured;  throws exception
        Public Sub New()
            Throw New Exception("I Crashed!")   'Emulate constructor crash
        End Sub
    End Class
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim obj As BrokenClass = New BrokenClass()  'Assignment causes constructor exception
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Sub Main(ByVal args As String())            'Main hasn't run yet.  No chance to assign handlers.
        Console.WriteLine("Main Running...Press ENTER to exit")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

*(My apologies for the bad colorization;  apparently VB doesn't colorize correctly in a code block)*

Comment: One good and simple way would be to instantiate your objects in the Main instead of the declaration, then you can catch the exception.

Comment: Just create an Initialize() method and put all the "new" calls there and call that method from the main in the first line. Wrap it all up in a try-catch.